# Why JavaScript evaluation must be awaited when using Xamarin Forms WebView?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview

The Xamarin.Forms.WebView control has an awaitable EvaluateJavaScriptAsync(string) function. A call to this function will not return unless the async/await pattern is used.

For example, the following function call will never return:

```
string result = webView.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("var a=2;").Result;
/* This call will never return */
```

But this works:

```
string result = await webView.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("var a=2;");
/* This works, and result is equal to string.Empty */
```

Can anybody give a good explanation to this behavior?

Comment: ...explanation to this behavior...? Calling `.Result` will block the current thread.

Comment: The `EvaluateJavaScriptAsync` function also uses the async/await pattern. If I block the current thread (by calling `.Result`), then I won't be able to be notified about the async task's completion, right? And this is why the call never returns. True?

Comment: In general `.Result` will block your thread until you get the Result and then return the current thread to execute, but there may be some unknown error when you call the js that keeps blockingthat keeps blocking.Therefore we usually use await when asynchrony.